# ObservableCollection to SQL database file, WPF

Tags: sql, wpf, database, collections

I have ObservableCollection for my Collection og Movie files. Im using ListView to display filename, size, type, length of movie files i add to my Collection. Im am now trying to build database to store the info i display with the ListView so when i close and open my program later previously addded files will be in the listview. I was thinking if there was some method to connect SQL database (using VS 2010 and SQL database file) to my Collection.

Or is it unneccecary to use collection if i am going to build database for my info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at LINQ to SQL

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/binding_in_linq-sql.aspx talks about using LINQ to SQL and WPF binding

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Object Relational Mapping tool commonly referred to as an ORM.
In the Microsoft Stack three possible solutions come to mind.

- [Linq To Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) I'm not sure if Microsoft is still actively supporting this anymore.
- [Entity Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) or EF4 the ORM Microsoft has been putting a lot of energy into.
- [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.com/) is an open source solution with a huge community around it.

There are a lot more just google "ORM .NET"

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to store all the information now and then retrieve all of them later, serialization (binary or XML) is much easier than using a database.